# Inverse Mellin's tranform of Pochhammer(quotient of Gamma functions)

Tags: indefinite-integrals, gamma-function, mellin-transform

I am trying to evaluate the reverse Mellin's transform for the pochhammer symbol.

I got to this equation:
$\frac{1}{2\pi \cdot i} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)} {\Gamma(s+k+1)} y^{-s}ds$.
$\sigma>0$ and $k$ can be any positive integer.

I don't know how to proceed. Could anyone help me with this evaluation?

I am not sure if I am heading the right direction

I tried $\Gamma(s)=\int^\infty_0e^{-u}u^s\frac{du}{u}$ and
$\Gamma(s+k+1)=\int^\infty_0e^{-u}u^{s+k+1}\frac{du}{u}$

I try to solve the $\frac{\int^\infty_0e^{-u}u^s\frac{du}{u}}{\int^\infty_0e^{-u}u^{s+k+1}\frac{du}{u}}$, but not sure what I can do next.

Comment: Please add what you tried and where you got stuck. Just posing a problem is almost never well-recieved on this site.

Comment: I see! I solved part of the question, and this is what I get so far. So I am stuck on this step... I don't know how to inverse this mellin transform.

Comment: I really appreciate your edits! Many thanks. @VincentBatens

Comment: Your first formula seems corrupted as it has the word "and" inserted in the middle of the MathJax. Are you trying to evaluate $\frac{1}{2\pi \cdot i} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(s+k+1)} y^{-s}ds$ which was your original formula before the corrupting edit?

Comment: Playing around with Mathematica I came up with $$\int_\limits0^1 \frac{(1-y)^k}{\Gamma (k+1)}\, y^{s-1} \, dy=\frac{\Gamma (s)}{\Gamma (k+s+1)}\,,\quad \Re(k)>-1\land \Re(s)>0$$ and so the inverse Mellin transform of $\frac{\Gamma (s)}{\Gamma (k+s+1)}$ is $\frac{(1-y)^k}{\Gamma (k+1)}\, (1-\theta(y-1))$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right! I accidentally put and inserted in the middle of the MathJax. Thank you so much. This Mathematica experiement gives a lot of insights!

Comment: Push the contour of integration through all the poles at $s=0,-1,-2,\ldots$ and use the residue theorem.

Comment: @Gary Thank you very much! I tried this method and it works!